# How to get previous element in a LinkedList?

Tags: java, linked-list

I am using a `LinkedList` and I want to get the previous (and the next) element, but not sure how to approach that.

My linked list:

```
LinkedList<Transaction> transactions = transactionRepository.findAll();
```

I am searching for this transaction:

```
Transaction targetTransaction = new Transaction("admin", new Date(), 5);
```

What I want to do:

```
for (Transaction transaction : transactions) {
    if (transaction.equals(targetTransaction)) {
        System.out.println("Previous transaction: " + transaction.getPrev());
    }
}
```

The `transaction.getPrev()` part does not work, because my Transaction object does not have such method.

Question: how to correctly obtain the "previous" object from the LinkedList?

Comment: This is easiest if you use a doubly linked list.

Comment: if you maintain which index you are at you can use that to get the previous.

Comment: Explicitly use a `ListIterator` instead of the enhanced for loop

Comment: Thank you all, guys. I was looking for an elegant solution using LinkedList. Iterating it as an array was my plan B. Looks like now I won't have to.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Enhanced `for` loop uses `Iterator` behind the scenes, and this interface doesn't provide any method to go to the previous element. Use [`LinkedList#listIterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#listIterator-int-) instead:

```
ListIterator<Transaction> li = transactions.listIterator(0);
while (li.hasNext()) {
    //your logic goes here

    //if you need to go to the previous place
    if (li.hasPrevious()) {
        li.previous();
        //further logic here...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep track of the previous `Transaction` as you go through the list.

```
Transaction prev = null;
for (Transaction transaction : transactions) {
    if (transaction.equals(targetTransaction)) {
        System.out.println("Previous transaction: " + (prev = null ? "[none]" : prev));
    }
    prev = transaction;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I think the accepted answer fits my situation better. But your input is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Keep track of what the last element was manually.

```
Transaction last = null;
for (Transaction transaction : transactions) {
    if (transaction.equals(targetTransaction)) {
        System.out.println("Previous transaction: " + last);
    }
    last = transaction;
}
```

Comment: It is stated in the question that `transaction.getPrev()` is nonexistent. How do you expect this to compile?

Comment: @Jashaszun forgot to update the `println`. Fixed now.

Comment: Also your answer is now exactly the same as mine (minus a tiny bit of error checking)...

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252795/how-to-deal-with-duplicate-answers

Comment: Although I guess that based on that meta question, both of our answers should be equivalently voted, so I guess we're good. :)

Comment: Thank you! I think the accepted answer fits my situation better. But your input is greatly appreciated.